# Lambda inside dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, functional-programming

I could not decipher how this function is working, could somebody explain what the brackets after the curly braces mean?

```
def max(a,b):
    f = {a >= b : lambda: a, b >= a: lambda: b}[True]
    return f()
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a dictionary comprehension, it seems to be just a straight dictionary literal. The `[True]` is just doing a lookup of the dictionary, and the resulting lambda is stored in `f`. When the lambda is called, it returns either `a` or `b`. This is exceedingly convoluted code though, and there's like 10 better ways that this could be written unless I'm missing something.

Comment: whoever wrote that code must have been seriously bored i guess.

Comment: Thank you. I see, then the brackets after a dictionary is a notation for searching keys to match what inside the bracket. True?.

Comment: @Tunity Yes. It's the same as if you had `{1:2}[1] # Returns 2`

Answer (score 0):

This is very convoluted (*strange*) definition for max, basically it creates a dictionary where the keys are the boolean `True` and `False` and the values are either `a` or `b` depending which one is the maximum. For example `max(1,2)` creates the following dictionary:

```
{ False: lambda: 1, True: lambda: 2}
```

Then `f` is assigned the function of the True value in the above example `lambda: 2`, which is a function that returns the constant value `2`. Finally the function returns the call of `f()`, i.e. the value `2`.

To answer your question more specifically, the brackets after the curly braces means get the value of the dictionary for the `True` key.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = {a >= b : lambda: a, b >= a: lambda: b}[True]
```

Above statement will always get evaluated as either one of the following:

case 1: a > b

```
f = {True : lambda: a, False: lambda: b}[True]
```

which means f = lambda: a

which means f() is a

case 2: b > a

```
f = {False: lambda: a, True: lambda: b}[True]
```

which means f = lambda: b

which means f() is b

case 3: a = b

```
f = {True : lambda: a, True: lambda: b}[True]
```

which means `f = lambda: a` or it could be f = lambda: b

which means f() is a or b

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the clusters and the lambda function, it's hard to understand!

But this example teaches something:

```
{"name": "Jundullah", "age": 18}["name"] #ouput: "Jundullah"
```